# JS. Если строка начинается с нуля, то удалить ноль

Tags: javascript

Строка может иметь до 30 цифр.

Как удалить первый символ, если он является нулем? Остальные нули в строке трогать не нужно.

Например:
01234 должно преобразовываться в 1234

Пытаюсь через условия и slice делать, но удаляется оба символа. Работать начинает только с 3 символа.

Comment: Покажите как делаете....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (s[0] === '0') s = s.slice(1)
```

Comment: Работает. Только  я делаю ==, а у вас ===

Comment: @Валерия_91, в данном случае без разницы

Comment: @Валерия_91, а зачем использовать 2, если можно 3? И если вопрос решён, то надо принять ответ нажав галочку слева от него.

Comment: @Qwertiy а зачем 3 если можно использовать 2 ?)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что не надо тип приводить.

Comment: @Qwertiy если контролировать тип и знать что делать - то от 0.00000001сек не убудет)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, моё мнение, что надо всегда использовать ===, кроме случаев, когда ты хочешь, чтобы приведение произошло.

Answer (score 2):

Более лаконичное решение:

```js
let cutFirstZero = (string) => {
  return string.startsWith('0') ? string.slice(1) : string;
};

console.log(cutFirstZero('0132'));
console.log(cutFirstZero('01032'));
console.log(cutFirstZero('132'));
console.log(cutFirstZero('132'));
console.log(cutFirstZero('00132'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```js
const a = "54545454";
const b = "045454500545";

const removeFirstZero = (str) => {
  if (str.startsWith("0")) {
    return str.slice(1);
  }

  return str;
};

console.log(removeFirstZero(b));
console.log(removeFirstZero(a));
```

Comment: решение ок, но пара корректировок: можно сделать чуть проще (тернарником и убрать return), но самое оснвное - функция названа некорректно. Написано что она что-то проверяет, а на самом деле проверяет и делает "обрезание" :D    так что нужно корректнее называть функции

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если убрать return, отличия не будет между моим и ответом и ответом Максима. Имя функции переписал. Спасибо :)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов ты дал ответ в 9:43, а я в 9:46... Я банально не видел твоего ответа, так как они сразу не показывались. Так что, не надо тут говорить, что я просто переписал... Наши с тобой решения совпали просто, не более того.

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин не ты, а вы, мы лично не знакомы. Во вторых, я не имел в виду, переписал, если вы так подумали тут я не виноват. В третьих, думайте все что хотите, но оставьте меня в покое.